# Is it possible to use a primitive type (int) in as a generic type in Java?

Tags: java, generics, types, primitive

Specifically, with a `SortedMap<Vector<String>, int>` I get "dimensions expected after this (`int`) token." Help!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Use `Integer` instead. Autoboxing takes care of the rest (i.e. for most purposes you can program as if you had actually used `int` because Java converts to and from `Integer` automatically for you).

Comment: @willcode…: You figured me out. :-/ If not for the badge, I would have given a wrong, thoroughly misleading answer that would have led the OP on a merry goose chase through the internet. Now, quick, get off the Internet. It's dangerous out here.

Comment: If not for the badge you would not have posted the question at all I suspect :)

Comment: @willcode…: I have *not* posted the question. I've just corrected the formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Konrad is correct.  Alternately, you can use the trove class TObjectIntHashMap to map Objects to primitive ints.