# Java simple generics

Tags: java, templates

How can I replace those 2 functions with one using something like C++ tempates?

```
public void verify(final int[] array, final int v) {
    for ( final int e : array ) if ( e == v || v == e  ) return;
    abort_operation();
}

public void verify(final double[] array, final double v) {
    for ( final double e : array ) if ( e == v || v ==  e  ) return;
    abort_operation();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use a primitive type (int) in as a generic type in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414408/is-it-possible-to-use-a-primitive-type-int-in-as-a-generic-type-in-java)

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but `e == v || v == e` is the same as just `e == v`.

Answer (score 12):

You can't, basically. Java generics don't work with primitive types. You *could* do it with reflection, but it would be ugly. You could also do it with the *boxed* types, like this:

```
public <T> void verify(T[] array, T value) {
   if (!Arrays.asList(array).contains(value)) {
       abortOperation();
   }
}
```

... but that would only work for `Integer[]` and `Double[]`, not `int[]` and `double[]`.

That's why the [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class has so many overloads for methods like `binarySearch`... if your method could have been made generic, so could those ones.

Fundamentally, generics are *not* the same as C++ templates. They cover a lot of the same use cases, but they're not the same, and you shouldn't be surprised to see some areas covered by one but not the other.

Comment: You can if you use the `Array` reflection class.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Yes, hence "You could do it with reflection" :)

Answer (score 2):

You can if you use the `Array` class

```
public void verify(final Object array, final double v) {
    for(int i = 0, len = Array.getLength(i); i < len; i++)
        if(((Number) Array.get(array, i)).doubleValue() == v)
             return;
    abort_operation();
}
```

or

```
public void verify(final Object array, final Number v) {
    for(int i = 0, len = Array.getLength(i); i < len; i++)
        if(((Number) Array.get(array, i)).equals(v))
             return;
    abort_operation();
}
```

Note: all possible `int` can be represented as a `double` so you can make `v` a double without loss of precision.

This will work for all the numeric primitives and Number types. (Note: some `long` values cannot be converted to `double` without loss of precision)

If `e == v` then `v == e` must also be true.

Comment: Why not just take `Number` instead of `double` and use `equals` instead? (That might have odd effects around NaN etc, but that's less likely to be a problem than `long`.)

Comment: @JonSkeet As you mentioned, its ugly.  The problem is that if you do `verify(new double[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 1)` it will fail.

Comment: Yes, you would need to make sure you pass in the right `Number` type. That's more likely to be an issue if you're using a primitive than a variable though, and I think I prefer it as a caveat to "long values may or may not work".

Answer (score 1):

You cannot - the varying type is primitive, and Generics doesn't cover primitives. Maying in Java 10-11...

Mind you, you can use boxed types and it will work, if you use equals instead of ==, and accept the horrible performance and memory footprint penaly...